# How create a regular expression for accented character in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby

I need create a regular expression that verifies accented character as á é í ó ú

How I fix my regular expression in order to it verifies accented character

/^ [a-z A-Z] {3,10} $/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put the accented character in there

```
/\A[a-zA-Záéíóú]{3,10}\z/
```

Ruby supports utf8 in your source code.

Comment: Thanks It worked perfect. I can see that too I can use [:alpha:]